# getting error with Webpack - couldn't find present "es2015"

Tags: webpack

```
ERROR in (webpack)/node_modules/process/browser.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/process"
```

this is my webpack config file:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: [
  './src/App.js',
  ],
  output: { 
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: ['node_modules'],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ab-site-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.4"
  }
}
```

I do not know what this error means.  I have tried getting webpack to work for days now.  Each error I get is not helpful and trying to solve it results in creating more errors.  I would appreciate any help.  I have a `.babelrc` file with the two presets `es2015`, and `react`.  I've seen people on the internet telling me to delete it.. to keep it.  Maybe my npm is out of date?  maybe my webpack is out of date?  Nothing I do works and everything I do only makes other errors crop up.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to configure babel presets: via babel-loader options

```
  options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
           }
```

or via .babelrc. Some prefer one way of doing things, some prefer the other. I use .babelrc.

This config works for me:

In **webpack.config.js**

```
{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      }
```

in **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Comment: i wonder if the problem was that i had a .babelrc file and was also specifying its config in my webpack config.   unfortunately i repasted some webpack config code from a previous revision i was working on and now webpack-dev-server boots up without this error, so in the end i never found out what the actual reason behind that error was!

Comment: It might  be, that you have webpack v3, which has slightly different syntax then webpack 1,  "loaders" are now "rules" and "query" is now "options". Checkout the new documentation: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

Comment: well i have `3.5.4` and i'm using 'loader' in my config file

Comment: Yeah, i checked - webpack v3 lets you use the old naming.

Comment: ah, so i guess i won't know what the problem was.  i did notice that sometimes i'd have to go and manually delete the bundle.js file and/or rerun webpack (not webpack-dev-server) for certain changes to take effect.  ultimately this has been a nightmare as far as errors go.  not very helpful..

Comment: the error was 'could't find preset "es2015" relative to directory` but when i replaced my webpack config file with a previous revision it worked.. but i didn't change any npm installs.. so that error makes no sense to me